# C# How to count number of rows in specific column on a data grid table

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count row on a specific column. I have this data on my data grid table.

> Date  ---------- TimeIn ------------TimeOut

```
05/16/2016 --- 08:00:00 AM --     05:00:00 PM

05/16/2016 --- 08:00:00 AM --
```

**I used**

```
lblCount.Text = DataGridTable1.RowCount.ToString();
```

and the output is 2.

How can i count the number of row of the column TimeOut? It's like that if I don't have any value on column TimeOut the row will not be counted.

So the output will be 1.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be counting non empty cells looping through column values, we could do this using `Linq` as below.

```
int count = dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => (string)row.Cells["TimeOut"].Value)
    .Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)) 
    .Count();
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answers for some time now. So what I did, I converted it into string so my label can read it. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to iterate through all the rows and count your desired column's row

like follow :

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

       if (rw.Cells["TimeOut"].Value == null || rw.Cells["TimeOut"].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhitespace(rw.Cells["TimeOut"].Value.ToString())
       {
         // here increase your counter
       }

    }
```

[ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255186/how-to-check-empty-and-null-cells-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp)